# Passing optional arguments to node.js script

Tags: node.js, npm

There is a script that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
"deploy-geneLib": "npx hardhat run ./scripts/000-deploy-geneLib.ts --network $npm_config_network" 
}
```

I want to make `--network` argument optional (if it is not passed to the script, it is being completely ignored). Is there a way to do this?